# To show $l^2a+\pi l b \in (\pi \mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^2$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_3$ be the $3$-adic field and $\mathbb{Q}_3(\zeta_3)$ be the cyclotomic extension and $\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3]$ and $M=\pi \mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3]$ be its maximal ideal. Let $(\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^{*}$ be the units in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3]$.

> I am trying to show $l^2a+\pi l b \in M^2$, where $|a|_3 \leq \frac{1}{3}$, $|b|_3 \leq \frac{1}{3}$ and $l \in (\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^{*}$ and $\pi=\sqrt{-3}$.

For simplicity, assume $|a|_3=|b|_3=\frac{1}{3}$ i.e., $a=b=3u^n$, $u \in (\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^{*}$. Then,

\begin{align*}
(l^2a+\pi lb)&= l^2a(1+\pi \cdot U), \ \text{where} \ U=1/l \in (\mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^{*}, \\
&=(3) \cdot \left\langle l^2 \right\rangle \cdot (1+\pi U)\\
&= (\pi^2) \cdot \left\langle l^2 \right\rangle \cdot (1+\pi U) \\&=(\pi \mathbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3])^2 \\&=m^2.
\end{align*}

So in cases $|a|_3=|b|_3=\frac{1}{3}$, we see $$l^2a+\pi lb \in m^2. $$
If we assume $|a|_3=|b|_3=\frac{1}{3^n}<\frac{1}{3}$,then also we get similar result. (please check it)

But how to deal the case when $|a|_3 \neq |b|_3$ provided $|a|_3 \leq \frac{1}{3}$, $|b|_3 \leq \frac{1}{3}$ ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|a|_3,|b|_3\leq\tfrac13$ then $a,b\in3\Bbb{Z}_3[\zeta_3]=M^2$, hence $l^2a+\pi lb\in M^2$.

Comment: Thanks. So it is true that $\left\langle l^2a+\pi lb \right\rangle=M^2$. Isn't it ?